# IF statement Not Recalculating Past Length of Referenced Spill Range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, spill-range

I have a column that is a spill range that uses the filter and sort_by formulas. This spill range is dynamic and I have an `IF` statement that references the spill range but upon recalculation of the sheet the `IF` statement doesn't recalculate past the length of the old spill range. Here is the spill range formula:

```
=SORTBY(
    FILTER(
        'Loss Template'!$E:$E,
        ('Loss Template'!$A:$A=TEXT($B$2,"0"))*('Loss Template'!$F:$F<=$J$7)*('Loss Template'!$F:$F>=$H$7)*('Loss Template'!$H:$H>2000)*('Loss Template'!$M:$M=5),
        ""
    ),
    FILTER(
        'Loss Template'!$M:$M,
        ('Loss Template'!$A:$A=TEXT($B$2,"0"))*('Loss Template'!$F:$F<=$J$7)*('Loss Template'!$F:$F>=$H$7)*('Loss Template'!$H:$H>2000)*('Loss Template'!$M:$M=5),
        ""
    ),
    1,
    FILTER(
        'Loss Template'!$H:$H,
        ('Loss Template'!$A:$A=TEXT($B$2,"0"))*('Loss Template'!$F:$F<=$J$7)*('Loss Template'!$F:$F>=$H$7)*('Loss Template'!$H:$H>2000)*('Loss Template'!$M:$M=5),
        ""
    ),
    1
)
```

Here is the `IF` statement:

```
=IF(
    $G10 <> "",
    IF(XLOOKUP($G10,'Loss Template'!E:E,'Loss Template'!G:G,,0)="Closed", "F", "O"),
    ""
)
```

I found out if I use Find and Replace "=" with "=", then it fixes the issue.

Should I code a workaround in my `update_macro` doing this? Or how can improve these formulas?

Note: I need an `Update_macro` because it is on manual calculation.

Comment: I'm confused. These look like excel formulas, not VBA. Can you post a screenshot of your work or a sample file?

Comment: use a worksheet change event tied to the relevant range that would trigger a need to recalculate... and have that macro calculate the relevant sheet

Comment: did you try `=IF(XLOOKUP($G10#,'Loss Template'!E:E,'Loss Template'!G:G,,0)="Closed", "F", "O")` Where G10 is the location of the formula that is spilling.

Comment: @PGSystemTester yes they are formulas.  I was under the impression that I could present problems such as this if I was willing to fix in VBA or Formulas.

Comment: Okay, you may not need VBA. Like I said, if you posted some screenshots you might get more feedback. A little hard to follow what the issue is.

Comment: @ScottCraner I will try that!

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the Spill Range identifier(#) and it works so far. thanks everyone for the help! Credit to @Scott Craner for the answer.

`=IF(XLOOKUP($G10#,'Loss Template'!E:E,'Loss Template'!G:G,,0)="Closed", "F", "O")`